# ASP.NET MVC - DataAnnotations for Client Validation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

If an ASP.NET MVC application using Data Annotations...

```
<%= Html.ValidationSummary("Things broke...") %>
<% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
```

And we post to the server.  Won't we still hit the action, check the ModelState.IsValid and come back to the original view with the validation error.  Is it still considered client side validation if we're hitting the server (via a post)?

Comment: Ok, so why do they call the function EnableClientValidation()?  Is it intended to do client validation?

Comment: The confusing part was why my textboxes were not validating client side.  It was because I wasn't using Html.ValidationMessage(textbox) for them or EditorForModel() (which includes the validation message for us in the template)!

Comment: I prefer using `Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName)` istead of `Html.ValidationMessage('FirstName')` to get type safety against the Model - you can also pre-compile your pages to pick up any issues with property names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, what you just said is not considered client side validation.

Client side validation is considered anything that validates the form in the browser (client), usually with JavaScript.  Once the post is sent to the server (ASP.net), then you are in server side validation mode.

**I believe what you are really asking though is whether the new asp.net mvc 2.0 validation is client side or not.**

**[EnableClientValidation](http://hadihariri.com/blogengine/post/2009/10/06/Client-Side-Validation-in-MVC-20.aspx)** enables your data annotated models to use the jquery validate plugin to do true client side validating.  It should not be posting back to the server to do the validating, but when it does post back it will probably validate on the server as well since client side validation is not 100% reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be server side validation. If you do the validation on the client side and avoid the form to be posted when any of the fields are invalid, then it's client side validation.

Answer (score 1):

If you add these libraries it will take care of the client validation.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MicrosofMVCValidation.js"></script>
```

These libraries will generate the javascript code for validation.
But for this you need to use [Dataannotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx)

Here is an [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) about it

Comment: I believe that the `Html.EnableClientValidation()` call adds these to the page on your behalf.